# Using VUETIFY with vue-sfc-rollup tool

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

Has anyone used VUETIFY with this tool vue-sfc-rollup?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-rollup

I need to add VUETIFY to the project that tool created, but using the VUE CLI command VUE ADD VUETIFY will not work due to the fact that the rollup solution is not a complete vuejs application, but a compact solution for creating distributed components.  **The problem I am trying to solve is where do I add the vuetify specific code?**

Comment: Please refactor your question to ask what specific problem that you're having. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial website, as it stands to attract generally bad or dated answers that are highly opinionated.